# Extract JSON table from JSON string element

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

I get this JSON in response from server:

```
{
   "tab":[
      "[[\"2018\",11,\"19\",\"16\",\"13\"],null,null,null,null,null,\"40\"]",
      "[[\"2018\",11,\"19\",\"16\",\"19\"],null,null,null,null,null,\"56\"]",
      "[[\"2018\",11,\"19\",\"16\",\"21\"],null,null,null,null,\"57\",null]"
   ]
}
```

I know, that I can get first element of `tab` table returned using `$.tab[1]`. The returned element is a string that holds a table - first element of this table is another table holding a date. The question is what JSON Path expression should I use in order to extract year value from the inner table or one of those numbers at the end (40, 56, 57)?

Comment: the numbers that you are trying to extract move around?

Comment: You want to extract the year or the numbers? Cuz `year value or one of those numbers at the end` isn't really specific.

Comment: No, they do not move, it's just an example. And I need both, that year and nubers at the end of outer table. I simply don't know what JSON Path expression should I use to get something out from that string that holds another table.

Comment: `$.tab[1]` returns the second element ...

Comment: Right, my mistake - it's second element. But that's not my problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you can get the first element with `$.tab[1]`. Are you using jQuery?  Even so, that doesn't seem to make any sense.  Regardless, you can parse those inner tables and access them normally as arrays:

```js
var results = {
   "tab":[
      "[[\"2018\",11,\"19\",\"16\",\"13\"],null,null,null,null,null,\"40\"]",
      "[[\"2018\",11,\"19\",\"16\",\"19\"],null,null,null,null,null,\"56\"]",
      "[[\"2018\",11,\"19\",\"16\",\"21\"],null,null,null,null,\"57\",null]"
   ]
};

// you can refactor this as a method for more convenient usage, this is just a demo
var row = JSON.parse(results.tab[0]);

// now you just have a multi-dimensional array, use it as normal
console.log(row[0][0]); //year
console.log(row[6]); //number
```

Comment: I am looking for a JSON Path expression that would allow me to get out values from that string. If that's possible...

Comment: Is it a requirement to use JSONPath, @WojtusJ?

Comment: Yes, I need to use it in a software that only allows me to apply JSON Path expression to the response I get from server. Using any other kind of processing - like JavaScript - would complicate the processing significantly.

Comment: In that case, I can't really see a good solution.  JSONPath only sees JSON structures and you essentially need to take the value of a JSON element and parse it, which JSONPath cannot do.  All it sees is a string.  You would need some level of post-processing.

Comment: I found a fairly easy way to use piece of JS code in my solution, and your code helped. Thanks a bunch!